# How to declare appium driver globally in karate config.js with desired capabilities?

Tags: karate

I am trying to declare and luanch appium driver session from config.js along with desired capabilities but i am not able to launch the driver session.

My feature file looks like below: (before declaring in config.js)

```
Background: Driver setup

* configure driver = { type: 'android', webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', start: false}
* driver { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : "#(desiredConfig)" } }

Scenerio: perform click
* click('elementPath')
```

Added below lines in config.js then i removed first line from feature file, it worked fine.

```
karate.configure('driver', { type: 'android', start: false, webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub' });
```

Then after that my feature file looks like below:

```
Background: Driver setup

* driver { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : "#(desiredConfig)" } }

Scenerio: perform click
* click('elementPath')
```

Now i am stuck in moving the

```
* driver { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : "#(desiredConfig)" } }
```

driver session part (above one) to config.js

Tried below things:

1. Created driver variable in config.js and assigned

   { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : desiredConfig } }
   Tried using driver variable in feature file
2. Declared desired config json directly and no luck

Comment: I have no idea. hope someone else helps you but I think your best option is to do some research and look at other answers

Comment: I think I got it - embedded expressions do NOT work in JS. read the docs (and next time make it more clear what you "tried" when you ask a question) https://stackoverflow.com/a/69965658/143475

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for the reply... 
Have tried declaring driver in config.js as variable then assigned { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : desiredConfig } }

Comment: tried adding desired config json directly and assigned to driver then tried calling driver from feature file, this approach also didn't work

Comment: @PeterThomas Edited question with few more details

Comment: sorry I have no more ideas. all the best